# Call to undefined function EvPeriodic()

Tags: php, pecl

I have tried the sample watcher example of php manual. but it is not working. i got an error : `Call to undefined function EvPeriodic()`. My Configuration information and code given below:

```
WAMP server : 2.2
PHP : 5.4.3
Apache : 2.2.22

<?php
    // Wait until STDIN is readable
    $w = new EvIo(STDIN, Ev::READ, function ($watcher, $revents) {
        echo "STDIN is readable\n";
    });
    Ev::run(Ev::RUN_ONCE);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `EvPeriodic` class is part of the `PECL ev` libary, from version 0.2.0 onwards. Are you sure you've added this module to PHP? (http://php.net/manual/en/class.evperiodic.php)

Comment: i have downloaded the ev-0.2.10.tgz and where should i place these foldee in wamp